# Matching prolog and plotmarkers sizes

Tags: plotting, labeling, size

Im trying to add some points to a ListPlot using Prolog. However, the point generated by Prolog is bigger than the Plotmarkers. How can I make them exactly the same size?

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 1, 5, 0.1}], 
 Prolog -> {{PointSize[0.03], Point[{4, 5}]}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{Disk[]}], 0.03}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the graphics primitives for `Prolog` using `ListPlot` with same plot markers:

```
marker = {{Graphics[{Disk[]}], 0.03}};

ListPlot[Table[{x, x}, {x, 1, 5, 0.1}], 
 Prolog -> {First @ ListPlot[{{4, 5}}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> marker]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> marker]
```

[image]